# Using issue, why do I have to use using global::MyName.SubName?

Tags: c#

I have a library project in my solution that I just added, and whenever I need to reference a class/enum I have to use:

`using global::MyName.SubName;`

(Resharper automatically suggests this)

Why is this?  Why can't I just do:

```
using MyName.SubName;
```

Which doesn't work. And even when it does this I am getting this error:

```
Error   400 Member 'MyName.SubName.Enumerations.SomeEnum.SomeEnumName1' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead
```

Comment: You probably have some ambiguity because of one or more identically named types from other namespaces. What other namespaces are you using?

Comment: @user1361315 Did my comments help?  Did this ever get resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume your `MyName.SubName` being hid (same name) by something else.

See the following MS article for more info:  [How to: Use the Global Namespace Alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx)

I think it explains the scenario you are running into.

> The ability to access a member in the global namespace is useful when
>   the member might be hidden by another entity of the same name.

...

> However, in larger projects, it is a very real possibility that
>   namespace duplication may occur in one form or another. In these
>   situations, the global namespace qualifier is your guarantee that you
>   can specify the root namespace.

Comment: So I have 2 projects:  MyProject.Web and the new project I created with is MyProject.Common.   I don't see any other namespace in MyProject.Web that has the word 'common' in it, so confused.  When I explore the code/namespaces, I don't see any conflict either.

Comment: @user1361315 you could be conflicting with something else from the framework.  The compiler is can't figure out what you are referring to so that should be why.  Static classes / methods can also create similar behavior but I think this is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @kelsey that it looks like a namespace conflict. Another way to resolve it is to use namespacing aliasing like;

```
using MNSub = MyName.SubName

// ...else where in code
MNSub.MyType varName = new MNSub.MyType();    // etc.
```

This at least gives a more meaningful syntax than `global::...`